# Access Spring MVC Service From Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring 3 and trying to populate the authorities of a Spring Security Authentication bean from the database after a user logs in.

I have a service that's used for accessing the database like

```java
@Service
public class UserService {
    public User getUser(String username){...}
}
```

Normally, I can `@Autowire` this service, but because the Authentication bean is created by the Spring Security, it can't seem to access the service. I also tried using the `ApplicationContextAware` interface, but Spring Security seems to have a separate `ApplicationContext`.

I can access the Authentication bean from MVC through `getUserPrincipal()` but is there a way I can access this @Service from somewhere in Spring Security authentication?

Comment: I'm not sure of understanding what you are trying to do. It seems you have a user registered to a service (i.e. the user is somwhere in the db), the user logs in, and you want to access the authorities of this user fetched from the db, is it right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's your setup or what you're trying to do but I'll try to help you based on a basic spring-security setup.

First of all, your UserService should implement [UserDetailsService](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html)

In your web.xml

```
<!-- Context Configuration locations for Spring XML files -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath*:META-INF/spring/some-application-service.xml
        /WEB-INF/security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

/WEB-INF/security.xml

```
<!-- 
  Assuming UserService is in com.sample.security package.
-->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sample.security"/>
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService" />
</authentication-manager>
```